# Load custom dynamic library(.dylib) in iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, dylib

I have created one custom library called 'Library.dylib',now I am trying to add that dylib file in another iOS project and it is giving following error,

> dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/Library.dylib   Referenced
>   from:
>   /Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4CCFE5F7-494B-41DE-AEB9-5040418518B4/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/A97A1947-80B5-9AA0-B46F-C11E25A94553/DyLibTest.app/DyLibTest
>   Reason: image not found

In Mac app if we copy it in /usr/lib/ path it is working, but not in iOS app.

Please let me know how to use custom dylib in iOS application?

FYI I want to use only dynamic linking not static linking(.a)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Make sure while adding that library you are ticking the option "copy items if needed" and also ticking your main target.

Comment: Hi @ParasGorasiya i am doing that already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see your app expects your library to be copied to `@executable_path/Library.dylib`. Yet, if you add your library to the `Embed Frameworks` build phase (which I assume you did) it will be copied to the `Frameworks` subfolder in your app bundle and therefore cannot be loaded by your app.

There are two solutions:

1) Change the destination of the `Embed Frameworks` build phase from `Frameworks` to `Executables`. In general, I wouldn't recommend to change that though.

2) Adjust the `Runpath Search Paths` in your build settings to include `@executable_path/Frameworks`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi @Jens Meder thanks for your answer,one thing I want to clarify is I am not using my .dylib inside any framework. I got my .dylib and placing it in app bundle. Instead of placing my dylib there, do I need to place some where else with any project settings?

Comment: Yepp, I didn't assume you have put your dylib in a framework. The thing is that dylibs a very similar to frameworks in the way the code is being loaded. Your executable needs to be able to load the code via the `Runpath Search Paths` so you need to make sure to copy the dylib to a location that your executable can find. Where do you copy the dylib at the moment?

Comment: Just now I have added images in the question, can you please look into those and help me where to copy that .dylib?

Comment: You just need to add it to the `Copy Files` build phase. The destination `Frameworks` is also correct for your `Runpath Search Paths` build setting.

Comment: Well, your dylib needs to be signed but Xcode takes care of everything as soon as you upload your app to the app store. There is no formal signing request or anything.

Comment: Hi @Jens Meder,now it is loading into app, but it is giving error like"_OBJC_CLASS_$_Show", referenced from:
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7,i set all valid architectures in lib target and all files were even included under compile sources build phase

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151359/discussion-between-jens-meder-and-ispark).

Comment: One more information: I had to use solution 1), changing "Runpath search paths" according to the destination, because the upload to App Store gave me the error "Invalid Bundle. The bundle contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'."

Answer (score 0):

You must put *.dylib file in Embed Libraries.

**Project -> Build Phases -> Embed Libraries**

Click to "+" and choose your *.dylib file.